# How to use WHERE and IN to update attributes in Neo4j comblined with LOAD CSV?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Hello assume I have 2 data files. They both have 2 columns. Like

file1 has column A and B(no real header in file) the content looks like:

1,   2

3,   4

...

file2 has column A' and B(no real header in file) the content looks like:

5,   2

3,   3

...

First I use the following code to build the A nodes, B nodes and relationships by file1:

```
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///home/nate/Downloads/file1.csv' AS line 
MERGE (n:A {number: toString(line[0])}) 
WITH line, n 
MERGE (m:B {ID : toString(line[1]), bonus: "YES"}) 
WITH m,n 
MERGE (n)-[:PAYS]->(m)
```

And now I want to change the "bonus" attribute of every B node to "NO" if B.ID appears in the second column of files 2. And of course add A' nodes if they don't exist after fisrt A nodes adding and the relationships between B nodes and A' nodes. I try to use WHERE and IN like this :

```
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///home/nate/Downloads/file2.csv' AS line 
match (b:B) 
where b.ID in({line[1]}) 
set b.bonus = "NO" 
return m
```

But it just doesn't work. Any ideas? Thx ahead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell there are a couple of issues you should be able to resolve.

Firstly I'd simplify the match in the second query. Below should more or less what you are after.

```
LOAD CSV FROM "file:/home/nate/Downloads/file2.csv" AS line
MATCH (b:B{ID: line[1]})
SET b.bonus = "NO"
```

The second problem I can see is that you attempt to return `m` in the second query but it has not been defined anywhere. Maybe you mean to say `RETURN b`.

Also you shouldn't really need to use the `toString` function when importing the CSV data. By nature the CSV data is already in string format.

Comment: Thx for your help!! But when I typed the above code the compiler says something wrong near "{line[1]}". And I changed it to just "line[1]" it runs but 0 rows changed. My guess is that there are multiple rows in file2 maybe neo4j is looking for B whose ID equals all line[1]??